# how to handle numeric keys from the phone keypad

Tags: android, android-layout

In following keypad:
[image]

we can select value by pressing buttons *(e.g  View button1.setOnClickListener(..)),* all i want to know is how can i handle keys(keys 0 to 9, enter_key, clear_key) from the phone keypad (e.g. when running on device other then tablet).

Please give a quick refference. any online tutorial will be highly helpfull.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go for onKeyDown which takes keycode and KeyEvent as arguments and KeyEvent class contains all the numeric codes:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0){
           //do some stuffs           
           }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) {
          // do some stuffs
           }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Like this you can handle numeric key press/.Hope it wil help you. :)